# Custom Basic Authentication in IIS7

Tags: ajax, iis, iis-7, cross-domain

I have basic authentication enabled in IIS7. The problem I'm having is that IIS is returning a **(Unauthorized 401)** error for the 'OPTIONS' requests. (given that 'OPTIONS' requests don't include Basic auth). Is there a way of configuring IIS7 to not require Basic auth for 'OPTIONS' requests? I've read various posts, but haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

Enable both Anonymous access and Basic Authentication. When you receive a request that requires authentication, ensure that a user other than the anonymous user has authenticated. If not, return a 401 error along with the appropriate authentication headers. The client should repeat the request with authentication information.

For requests that do not require authentication, continue processing.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I would like to achieve this without modifying my Web API. Basically, I just need to allow any incoming 'OPTIONS' requests and authenticate all other HTTP verbs.

Comment: I don't know if I can configure IIS7 in such a way.

Comment: I don't believe you will be able to achieve this with IIS out of the box. You may be able to create a custom authentication module to do this.